# Better way to increment +1 in laravel query?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to increment +1 the value i get with the query.

The query is this:

```
$project->order = DB::table('projects')
    ->where('order', DB::raw( "( select max(`order`) from projects )" ))
    ->get();
```

I think i should do something with increment, or just put +1 in the query, but not.

What's the better way to do it?

Thanks !

Comment: You can increment a value using DB::table('projects')->where('order', DB::raw("(select max(`order`) from projects)")->increment('your_value');

Comment: Why do you need that? It would be a data race there.

Comment: @Adrenaxus `increment` wil increment the value of the product that have the max order witch is not what is requested

Comment: @Adrenaxus i try something like your code but with get in the end, anyway if i copy your syntax give me a syntax error.

Comment: @zerkms i have a form to create new projects, projects have a field value called order, so i don't want to check the last order project and put the last order project +1 in a form, i think it's not efficient. This is why i want to put it on the controller!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$project->order = DB::table('projects')
                      ->where('order', DB::raw("(select max(`order`) from projects)"))
                      ->first()
                      ->order + 1;
```

Comment: `Property [order] does not exist on this collection instance.` I think, if i put something on the query, must be before get?

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer  Try my Edit :)

Comment: It works!, the differente is before ,you are using get and now you use first(), true?

Comment: Yes `get` returns collection but `first` return the first element

Comment: know why i get the error: `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`when try to get the id? @Maraboc

Comment: get id of what exactly ?

Comment: `$projecttranslation0->project_id = DB::table('projects')
                ->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from projects)"))->first();` I try to found the answer in others questions here, on stackoverflow, but not works. @Maraboc

Comment: You should do it like this : `$projecttranslation0->project_id = DB::table('projects') ->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(id) from projects)"))->first()->id;`

Comment: That's make me understand perfectly the query;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150732/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-maraboc).